# JavaScript crypto hashing translation to Python 3

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography

I am trying to make a Python 3 application to download weather data from my account at http://www.osanywhereweather.com. I have found JavaScript source code that does exactly this at https://github.com/zrrrzzt/osanywhereweather. I am assuming that the github code works. When inspecting the source of osanywhereweather.com, it seems to me that the github code resembles that very much.

I am new to Python 3 and I have never coded in JavaScript, and I know nothing about cryptographics. I have, however, done a fair share of coding over the last 35 or years, so I read code fairly well. I therefore thought it would be relatively easy to translate the github JavaScript code to Python 3. I was wrong, it seems.

The code of interest is the part of the code that hashes e-mail and password together with a "challenge" received from osanwhereweather.com in order to authenticate me.

I have not been able to test the JavaScript code, but as I said I think it compares well with the source of the osanywhereweather.com page. By analyzing the traffic in my web browser, I can see the information exchanged between osanywhereweather.com and my browser, so that I have got a consistent set of `challenge` and `saltedHash`.

When trying to create the same `saltedHash` based on the corresponding `challenge` with my Python 3 code, I get a different result.

I have tried internet searches to see if I can find out what I'm doing wrong, but to no avail. If anyone is proficient in JavaScript, Python and cryptographics and is able to point out what I'm doing wrong, I would indeed be grateful.

JavaScript code:

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');

function osaHash(email, password) {
  var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(email);
  var e = '$p5k2$2710$' + shasum.digest('hex').toString().substring(0, 8);
  var res = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, e, 1e4, 32, 'sha256');
  var r = res.toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '.');

  return e + '$' + r;
}

function createHash(opts, callback) {

  if (!opts) {
    return callback(new Error('Missing required input: options'), null);
  }

  if (!opts.email) {
    return callback(new Error('Missing required param: options.email'), null);
  }

  if (!opts.password) {
    return callback(new Error('Missing required param: options.password'), null);
  }

  if (!opts.challenge) {
    return callback(new Error('Missing required param: options.challenge'), null);
  }

  var hash = osaHash(opts.email, opts.password);
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', hash).update(opts.challenge);
  var saltedHash = hmac.digest('hex');

  return callback(null, saltedHash);
}

module.exports = createHash;
```

Python 3 code:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

e_mail = 'me@mydomain.com'
password = 'Secret'

''' challenge is received from osanywhereweather.com '''
challenge = '15993b900f954e659a016cf073ef90c1' 

shasum           = hashlib.new('sha1')
shasum.update(e_mail.encode())
shasum_hexdigest = shasum.hexdigest()
shasum_substring = shasum_hexdigest[0:8]
e                = '$p5k2$2710$' + shasum_substring

res = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256',password.encode(),e.encode(),10000,32)
r = base64.b64encode(res,b'./')
hashstr = str(e) + '$' + str(r)

hmac1 = hmac.new(challenge.encode(), hashstr.encode(), 'sha1')
saltedHash = hmac1.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hashstr = str(e) + '$' + str(r)
```

In the above line, `str(r)` will give you: `"b'ZogTXTk8T72jy01H9G6Y0L7mjHHR7IG0VKMcWZUbVqQ='"`.

You need to use `r.decode()` to get `"ZogTXTk8T72jy01H9G6Y0L7mjHHR7IG0VKMcWZUbVqQ="`.

```
hashstr = str(e) + '$' + r.decode()
```

**UPDATE 1**

Arugments to [`hmac.new`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new) should be fixed:

```
hmac1 = hmac.new(hashstr.encode(), challenge.encode(), 'sha1')
```

**UPDATE 2**

*According to OP's comment, OP doesn't need to do the following.*

Another thing is that, `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` seems does not respect `digest` argument. It seems always use `sha1` digest (At least in my system, NodeJS 0.10.25). So you need to specify `sha1` in python side:

```
res = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', password.encode(), e.encode(), 10000, 32)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, falsetru! With `r.decode()` and UPDATE 1 I get `saltedHash` to become the same result as exchanged between my browser and the web site. With UPDATE 2, however, the results becomes different again, so it seems I have to stick with `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on falsetru's response, the following Python 3 code has been verified to work with the osanywhereweather.com site:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

e_mail = 'me@mydomain.com'
password = 'Secret'

''' challenge is received from osanywhereweather.com '''
challenge = '15993b900f954e659a016cf073ef90c1' 

shasum           = hashlib.new('sha1')
shasum.update(e_mail.encode())
shasum_hexdigest = shasum.hexdigest()
shasum_substring = shasum_hexdigest[0:8]
e                = '$p5k2$2710$' + shasum_substring

res = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256',password.encode(),e.encode(),10000,32)
r = base64.b64encode(res,b'./')
hashstr = str(e) + '$' + r.decode()

hmac1 = hmac.new(hashstr.encode(), challenge.encode(), 'sha1')
saltedHash = hmac1.hexdigest()
```

Thank you to falsetru!